# Need help with generating colour id map!

Tags: texturing, uv, color

I'm trying to find an easy way to generate Color ID maps in blender to use in Quixel, Substance painter or designer. But there doesn't seem to be any sure shot easy way. I don't have access to Maya or 3ds max but I do have substance bundle, zbrush and 3D coat.

I do all my modelling and UV mapping work in blender, So It would be really helpful if I can easily generate quality color id maps for my assets before putting them in substance for texturing. I've tried assigning different emissive materials on the mesh and trying to bake textures in cycles. But its really time consuming for complex meshes.I also tried using [this addon](http://www.polycount.com/forum/showthread.php?t=140883) with a low poly mesh with red, green and blue materials applied on different faces but it gives a black and white result something like this.
[image]

Please help me with this.

Comment: Wow, duplicate??? Have you even read the complete details?